# Reduced size WebView not showing videos correctly in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I'm developing an application for tablets that utilizes two fragments on screen at the same time.  The right fragment contains a WebView that should be able to play videos, but it seems the reduced size of it's parent is preventing some videos from playing correctly.

*EDIT* I have simplified my example to exclude fragments and break the problem down to it's fundamentals:
Main:

```
public class TesterProjectActivity extends Activity {

WebView webView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webieView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSxSyv4LC1c");

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
}
```

Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webieView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="400dp"
        android:layout_width="800dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

At first I thought something was wrong with my video playback period, but after going over all possibilities, (I have hardware acceleration set to on in the manifest) I found that the videos play when the fragment containing the webview is made a little larger.

Note that when the WebView is made larger, the video plays, but a portion of the video gets cutoff for no reason.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  How can I get videos to play correctly in a WebView that lives in a fragment on only half of the screen?

I can't yet post images to this site (and am limited to only 2 links) but here are some links to screenshots of my issue:

Video playing:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/device20120323001322.png/

Also note that I tried using a WebViewFragment without any luck.

*EDIT* I have determined that the video plays, but it plays as if it's canvas is drawn from the top left corner.  No matter where the webView is, no matter where the video is in the WebView, the video's canvas only entails where the video would be playing if it was playing in the top left corner.  I updated my screenshots above to demonstrate this fact.

Comment: Anyone have any input into my issue?

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions or any input please answer this question.  If you can confirm that this is an unexpected issue please upvote this question to help me find a workaround.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I got the same problem...

Comment: No I have not found a solution.  I should probably move on but every time I go to make progress on my project I keep thinking I can find a solution to make videos play in my project correctly.

Comment: @BoostHungry, any solution found yet? I also got the same issue. One thing isolated that it is observed only on Samsung Galaxy Tab2 -10.1 inch - OS-4.0.3. I tried on a different make tab, but I faced another weird issue, which is not related to this. I explored a lot but couldn't find a solution. Webview shows only part of the video, rest shows blank/white!!!

Comment: No sorry I have not.  This is just another side project I worked on until it was no longer fun and then I moved on to something else.  If it wasn't for this issue, I probably would have seen this app through to completion.